# c++ elusive segmentation fault

Tags: c++, class, pointers, segmentation-fault

Im working on this bit of code and I keep getting a segmentation fault. For the life of me I cant figure out why, I know a segmentation fault is when you  try to follow a null pointer, but the thing is, in my code "u->previous" isnt null, neither is "u", I checked. If I change the condition in the while loop to (u != NULL), it will iterate twice before faulting on "u->isGreen", Once again, I checked every iteration to see if u was null.

```
int extractOptimalPath() {
    Node *u = nodes[NUM_NODES - 1];

    int i = 0;
    while (u != NULL) {
        cout << i << endl;
        u->isGreen = true;
        u = u->previous;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

"nodes" is an array of pointers to actual Node objects. I know for sure that the "u->previous" exists in my nodes and "isGreen" is initialized to false;

Heres the Node class, in case you want to see that:

```
class Node {
    public: 
        GLfloat x, y, z;
        int numLinks;
        Node *link1;
        Node *link2;
        GLfloat distance;
        Node *previous;
        bool isGreen;

        Node(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, Node *link1, Node *link2);
        Node(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, Node *link1);
        Node();
        Node(GLfloat x, GLfloat y);
        ~Node();

        bool dijkstra(Node* graph[], Node *source, Node *target); //returns true if a path to target is found
        int dist(Node *n1, Node *n2);
        int extractOptimalPath(Node* graph[]);
};
```

What could be causing the seg fault?

Comment: you should include the implementation of the `Node` class too.

Comment: What is the relationship between `extractOptimalPath()` and `extractOptimalPath(Node* graph[]);` ?

Comment: Have you used a debugger? It might help in knowing what exactly `u` is pointing to (it's not really enough to know it's not `0`).

Comment: ah, i was just testing and i moved it out of the class definition.

Comment: If you're on a platform that supports it, run your code through `valgrind`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error isn't *just* for null pointers, it is a pointer that points to anything invalid. That can be null, but it can also be memory that was freed.

Comment: Additional reasons might include a node corrupted by a rogue write or using a node that's not properly initialized.

Comment: I think you're right about it being memory thats been freed.(debugged it) What needs to be done to stop it from being freed?

Comment: @Matt: not freeing it. Using smart pointers and RAII, and following the Rule of Three (all of these are well documented on SO and on Wikipedia and other places)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a copy constructor in Node, while I see pointers and a destructor. So you violated the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

As a result, if you accidently copy a Node, that copy's destructor will result in effects you see now.

**Update:**
To quickly test for this, add a private copy constructor to your Node class, like this:

```
class Node {
...

private:
  Node(const Node&);
};
```

If you get compiler errors now, you are making copies. The compiler will point you to the locations where that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a NULL pointer to have a Segmentation Fault, it happens every time you access memory out of your allowed scope. Check the thread [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault).

Your code isn't sufficient to say what causes a segfault. Most likely `u->previous` in one of your nodes points to some more or less random place in memory, but it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in your constructor of a Node object, the previous pointer is never set to NULL at any point. You should have a point when previous is set to NULL (in your actual code, don't assume the code does this for you automatically). Also, as a tip, try using [gdb to step through your code](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/). Another tip, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is usually used to consult memory leaks, but I've used it to successfully pinpoint segfaults as well.